# Combining sparse and einsum to perform large sparse sum

Tags: python, arrays, sparse-matrix, numpy-einsum

I have a matrix A with shape=(N, N) and a matrix B with the same shape=(N, N).
I am constructing a matrix M using the following einsum (using the [opt_einsum](https://optimized-einsum.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library):

```
M = oe.contract('nm,in,jm,pn,qm->ijpq', A, B, B, B, B)
```

This is evaluating the following sum:

[image]

This yeilds matrix M with shape (N, N, N, N). I then reshape this to a 2D array of shape (N**2, N**2)

```
M = M.reshape((N**2, N**2))
```

This must be 2D as it is treated as a linear operator.

I want to use the [sparse](https://sparse.pydata.org/en/stable/) library, as M is sparse, and becomes too large to store for large N. I can make A and B sparse, and insert them into the `oe.contract`.

**The problem is, sparse only supports 2D arrays and so fails to produce the 4D output of shape (N, N, N. N). Is there a way to combine the einsum and reshape steps to allow sparse to be used in this way, as the final shape of M is 2D?**

Comment: `opt_einsum` is a third party library that few of us have worked with (is there even a `tag` for it?).  A quick glance at the docs does not indicate whether it can work with `sparse` matrices.  `np.einsum` certainly can't.

Comment: @hpaulj `opt_einsum` certainly does support `sparse` matrices, as indicated in the docs (https://optimized-einsum.readthedocs.io/en/stable/backends.html): "The sparse library also fits the requirements and is supported...."

Comment: @hpaulj FWIW `opt_einsum` gets about 6M downloads/month, many use it without knowing it (tensorflow is a prime example) and the older algorithms are implemented in `np.einsum`. It doesn't always work as well as you would like in SO examples, as they are typically small meaning BLAS costs more than direct einsum and/or the scaling issues with naive einsum do not play a large role. (Disclaimer: author of opt_einsum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not correctly interpret the error given by `opt_einsum`.

The problem is **not** that sparse does not support ND sparse arrays (it does!), but that I was not using a true einsum, as the indices summed over appear more than twice (`n` and `m`). As stated in the `opt_einsum` documentation this will result in the use of the sparse.einsum function, of which none exists. Using only 1 or 2 of each index works. Using a differerent path, one suggested for example by hpaulj can be used to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, in this case we need to cast the spare arrays back to dense NumPy ndarray which is quite suboptimal. We have a hard time finding general heuristics of how to perform the above outer products to improve GEMM performance, but if you have ideas let us know here: https://github.com/dgasmith/opt_einsum

Answer (score 1):

This may not help with your use of `opt_einsum`, but with a bit of reorganizing I can speed up `np.einsum` quite a bit, at least for small arrays.

Do a partial product of two `B`:

```
c1 = np.einsum('in,jm->ijnm',B,B).reshape(N*N,N,N)
```

The `pq` pair is the same, so we don't need to recalculate it:

```
c2 = np.einsum('nm,onm,pnm->op',A,c1,c1)
```

I verified that this works for two (3,3) arrays, and the speed up is about 10x.

We can even reshape the `nm` to 1d, though this doesn't improve speed:

```
c1 = np.einsum('in,jm->ijnm',B,B).reshape(N*N,N*N)
c3 = np.einsum('n,on,pn->op',A.reshape(N*N),c1,c1)
```